# One element makes another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have sortable elements in different sortable groups. I would like to use one element as a tool to add new elements. It should work this way: When a user drags this "add new" element to specific position there should be created new element and dragged one ("add new") should stay on it's previous position.

Do you have any idea if this is possible?

Comment: I think your forgot to paste `code`

Comment: I wrote an example ... My code is pretty messy (I do some tests) and I made nicer looking example... 
http://jsfiddle.net/2jBX2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, this link may give you some idea of how to do it. Try the demo given on this page.

[link:- [http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert]](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert)

```
// Here is the code copied from the same page. I have modified it a bit.
$(function() {  

    // Element which you will drag
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ revert: "valid" });   

    // Element to which you will drag the above(draggable) element.
    // On 'drop' event of this droppable you can add the element.
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      activeClass: "ui-state-default",
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {

          /*Write code for adding new item in the sortable list here*/        
      }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: OK This might be solution... I didn't even think to combine with dragable elements. On the other hand I believe that combining is not necessary. I think it could all be solved using sortable.. I wrote example code in comment above.

Comment: This one helped me ...

Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/eagerwolf/WafwY/

I can cancel the same way as suggested but also receive position!